# Datatype declaration by datatype in Standard ML

Tags: types, sml, isabelle, polyml

I'm trying to read the source of Isabelle even though I'm a beginner of Standard ML.
I arrive at the structure `Unsynchronized` in [src/Pure/Concurrent/unsynchronized.ML](https://github.com/seL4/isabelle/blob/85506e784adb5140c2a9cc09459f5dbfba489be0/src/Pure/Concurrent/unsynchronized.ML), which seems for the multi-thread programming. It includes

```
...

structure Unsynchronized: UNSYNCHRONIZED =
struct

datatype ref = datatype ref;

...

end;

ML_Name_Space.forget_val "ref";
ML_Name_Space.forget_type "ref";
```

and I cannot understand `datatype ref = datatype ref;`. It's not in the *usual* form of datatype declaration.

As an experiment, in the REPL of poly/ML, I got

```
> datatype ref = datatype ref;
datatype 'a ref = ref of 'a
```

and so this declaration seems doing nothing or giving a type constructor synonym `Unsynchronized.ref` = `ref` (also `Unsynchronized.ref` seems not being distinguished from `ref` at all).

So my questions are:

1. What kind of syntax structure does `datatype ref = datatype ref;` have?
2. What is the semantics (or meaning?) of `datatype ref = datatype ref;`?
3. What is the usage of such a type constructor synonym declaration? (Just for the clarity in semantics?)

Addendum: The functions

```
ML_Name_Space.forget_val
ML_Name_Space.forget_type
```

are defined in [src/Pure/ML/ml_name_space.ML](https://github.com/seL4/isabelle/blob/85506e784adb5140c2a9cc09459f5dbfba489be0/src/Pure/ML/ml_name_space.ML)
as

```
val forget_val = PolyML.Compiler.forgetValue;
val forget_type = PolyML.Compiler.forgetType;
```

and so after loading (?) `unsynchronized.ML`, the original type constructor `ref` is not available anymore. Probably, this answers Q.3 partially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
datatype ref = datatype ref
```

means that we create a synonym for the SML builtin type ref. It has the same constructor (`ref`) as the original one.

The commit does not provide any motivation why this was introduced, but I would not be surprised to hear that this comes from

(i) supporting the compilers PolyML and Moscow ML.

(ii) putting ref into a proper module for more clarity, making it possible to call other datypes `ref` (there is one in `src/Pure/facts.ML`)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also find the grammar for `datatype ref = datatype ref` in Appendix G. 6 of "The Definition of Standard ML (Revised)". I didn't know this declaration "Replication of Datatypes". Also, your remark on `src/Pure/facts.ML` motivates the replication very clearly.

I cannot understand the point (i), but it's maybe just because my lack of experience and I only care poly/ML in the current source code reading.

Comment: Anyway, I should have consulted the "definition" though it is difficult to follow for a beginner like me.

Comment: A long time ago, Isabelle supported several SML compilers. And they slightly differed in their semantics (IIRC moscow ml required some additional ';' at the end of modules definition).  Maybe there was some difference in module `ref` is in.

Comment: Ah... I see (probably). I also confused once on the type of `chr` in Poly/ML (int -> char) and in Isabelle/ML (int -> string) and this is an incompatibility of SML '90 and SML '97. (Later I found `chr` is redefined in Isabelle/ML.) In "Definition (revised)", I now found that ';' matter is also in 90 vs 97 incompatibility... Such subtlety is a bit difficult for me...

Anyway, thank you very much, Mathias!